# Antisymmetry of the total molecular wave function in case of orthohydrogen

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hydrogen, molecules

If my understanding is right, the total wave function of any system containing electrons and protons (and any other fermions for that matter) must be antisymmetric under exchange of the respective fermion. Consequently, the total wave function of the $H_2$
molecule must be antisymmetric under exchange of its electrons and under exchange of its protons.

Now, if the total wave function consists of a rotational and vibrational part, as well as a spin and spatial part for each electron and proton, how is it that the rotational part is required to be antisymmetric if the proton spin wave function is symmetric (i.e. orthohydrogen)? Wouldn't it suffice for the spatial part of the proton wave function to be antisymmetric, or is the molecular rotation connected to the spatial part of the proton wave function?